# What does "variable-free L-term" mean?

Tags: first-order-logic

Our lesson source is Lou van den Dries's Mathematical Logic Lecture notes. As a beginner, I do not understand the definition of $variable-free$ L-term. On pg.29, it says that "A term is said to be variable-free if no variables occur in it". As far as I understand, this means, variable-free term is a function symbol. But there are $variables$ in function interpretation unless the function is of arity 0. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A term is said to be *variable-free* if no variables occur in it.

In the language of arithmetic, these are *terms* :

> $x, y, x+y, 0, 0+x, 0+0, \ldots$.

Only : $0$ and $0+0$ are *variable-free* (i.e. "closed" terms) : they acts as "names" for objects in the *domain*.

A terms is variable-free if it is a *constant* (like : $0$) or built-up with an $n$-ary function symbol $f^n$ (like the binary : $+$) and $n$ variable-free terms $t_i$.

Comment: So, if it is built up with an $n$-ary function symbol, then it is evaluation of that function at those variable free terms, right?

Comment: @Serpenche - exactly: $+(0,1)$ is the value of the "complex" name built up from binary function symbol $+$ and the two constants $0$ and $1$. More complex example : $\times (1,+(0,1))$.

Comment: If $\mathbb N$ is the underlying set for some $L$-structure, then the elements of $\mathbb N$ that satisfy a specific formula have $names$ like $\underline 0$, $\underline 1$, etc.? Why this is needed? Why do not we just say 0 and 1 satisfies this formula and leave the numbers as they are? I know that's a naive question, but I can not help.

Comment: @Serpenche - it is the "formal" aspect of logic. We have the "world" of *numbers* : $0,1,\ldots$ and the *language* we speak about the world. The language has symbols and, specifically, *names* to name objects: the *numerals* : $\underline 0, \underline 1$. They are symbols. When we consider an *expression* of the language : $x=\underline 0$ we use names for objects and not the objects themselves.

Comment: My goodness, so $\underline 0$ is just the word "$zero$" we utter?

Comment: @Serpenche - yes; in some context, it is useful to "have control" of the object language (the f-o theory for arithmetic) and of the meta-language (the math-english we use to discuss about the formal theory). In this case "$0$" is the name we use in the meta-language to refer to the number while "$\underline 0$" is the "formal" name we use in the object language. Why so ? in some case we can consider models different from the "standard" one. For example, we may consider a domain with a single object (e.g. the number : square root of $2$) and use this object as denotation for ...

Comment: ... the single constant $\underline 0$ of the language. In this case $\underline 0$ is not the same as $0$ any more.